# SQL Sub-Query Filter Causes NULL value to be returned?

Tags: sql, sql-server

DISCLAIMER: I am very new to SQL, please be gentle.

I am trying to filter a subquery for certain values, but when I do, it causes the values to report back as NULL.

Here is the first query, without trying to filter the subquery:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime

SET @StartDate = '2019-09-10 00:00:00'
SET @EndDate = '2019-09-10 00:00:02'

SELECT [DateTime]
      ,Value AS [Line Speed]       
      ,(
        SELECT Value
        FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory C
        WHERE TagName = 'V800' AND A.[DateTime] = C.[DateTime]
       ) AS [FPS%]

FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory A
WHERE TagName = 'LS' 
    AND [DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
    AND [wwRetrievalMode] = 'Cyclic' 
    AND [wwResolution] = 1000 
    AND wwValueDeadband = '1'
```

And the output:

[image]

If I add: `AND Value = 0` onto the WHERE clause in the subquery, I get:

[image]

I've added `AND Value IS NOT NULL`, but that doesn't change the output.

EDIT: Interestingly enough, if I change it to `Value = 100`, that shows up in the output.

Is there a way to actually filter this so I don't pull all records and without replacing the real value with NULL?

EDIT2*

```
SELECT ah.[DateTime], ah.Value AS [Line Speed], ah2.[FPS%]     
FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory ah CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ah2.Value AS [FPS%]
      FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory ah2
      WHERE ah2.TagName = 'V800' AND 
            ah2.wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' AND
            ah2.wwResolution = 1000 AND
            ah2.wwValueDeadband = '1' AND
            ah2.[DateTime] = ah.[DateTime]
     ) AS ah2
WHERE ah.TagName = 'LS' AND
      ah.[DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND
      ah.wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' AND
      ah.wwResolution = 1000 AND
      ah.wwValueDeadband = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a lateral join, which in SQL Server uses the `apply` keyword.  This is a lot like a subquery in the `from` clause -- and can be quite handy:

```
SELECT ah.[DateTime], ah.Value AS [Line Speed], ah2.[FPS%]     
FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory Ah CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ah2.Value as [FPS%]
      FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory ah2
      WHERE ah2.TagName = 'V800' AND ah2.[DateTime] = ah.[DateTime]
     )  ah2
WHERE ah.TagName = 'LS' AND
      ah.[DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND
      ah.wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' AND
      ah.wwResolution = 1000 AND
      ah.wwValueDeadband = '1';
```

`CROSS APPLY` only returns rows where there is a match in the subquery (or function call).  `OUTER APPLY` would be used to get all values.

Comment: I've tried both `APPLY`s and they appear to run, however, it looks like the value reported is not changing (but definitely changes in the table).  It also looks like it's pulling 101 rows for each second, whereas before it was just pulling 1 row per for each second (wwResolution = 1000)

Comment: @Beutler . . . There was an error in the correlation clause.  I fixed that and a few other more minor things.

Comment: A few subtle changes ;)  I tried that and the query now returns nothing.  I also added some retrieval specifications to try to ensure they were time synced (see EDIT2 in post). It seems  `ah2.[DateTime] = ah2.[DateTime]` pulls 101 rows per second, but the `ah2.[DateTime] = ah.[DateTime]` seems to fail to pull anything

Comment: @Beutler . . . If that worked in your original query, it should work here.